# Set column values of a table based on another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `Employees` and `Pharmacies`.

In table `Employees` I have a column name `Pharmacy` which tells me what pharmacy an employee works at, and also a column with the names of the employees.

In table `Pharmacies` I have a column of pharmacies and I want to add a new one named `Number_of_employees` which to contain the number employees from the corresponding pharmacy where he works.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: Yes, DONT DO THIS. Instead write a query/view to count the employees using these 2 tables, then the number will ALWAYS be correct. If you store this count, there is every possibility it will be wrong most of the time

Comment: Create a *view* to return your data on the fly.

Comment: That relation is not very strong, so you'd probably would want to skip pharmacies table and perform an entire search on employees and compile that result. But if you had to for caching or stronger relationships, you'd update both tables at the same time? There's also jobs MySQL can take on but I'd move away from that and manually insert.

Comment: Arguably a better design would be to have employees, pharmacies and a junction table - this way if an employee works at more than 1 pharmacy you can cope with it easily,

Comment: `COUNT()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()` , You can do it in `SQL` , you should read about  `GROUP BY` ... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DON'T ADD the column `Number_of_employees`**

you can return `Number_of_employees` value by query

```
Select Pharmacies.*, count(Employees.Pharmacy) as Number_of_employees from Pharmacies
     join Employees on Pharmacies.id = Employees.Pharmacy
group by Employees.Pharmacy
```

Comment: I would be wary of using Pharmacies.*

Comment: yes bro , thank you for your addition

Comment: Yes bro, I guess it's the best choice. I gave up on that column. I'd have another question if you'd be kind to answer. I have a table loyal_customers, this table contains a the name of the customers, date when they became loyal custemers, a phone number and the pharmacy where they make a fidelity card. I want to not be possible that a customer to sign in for a fidelity card at the same pharmacy whith the same number. If James want a fidelity card for a pharm, let's call it Pharm1 with the number phone1, won't be able to sign in twice with the same number. Instead he can sign to another pharm